# Is it possible to run a JQL query using the JIRA SDK version 11.2

Tags: c#, linq, sdk, jira, jql

Is it possible to run a JQL query using the Atlassian.Jira nuget package (version 11.2). I can successfully connect to and return Issues using a c# linq query but I need to limit the response to only return issues where time has been spent within a particular timeframe recorded by a specific user. To do that I need to reference the worklog but that doesn't seem accessible via a linq queryable object. I can do it via JQL when searching for queries directly in JIRA.